# Excel VBA code to replace empty cell with adjacent (column) cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file where some of the column information is blank. I want to fill the blank cells with information from the two columns that come after the empty cell. For instance:

Column E is the full name of a person. Column F is their first name, Column G is their last name.

So, if E is blank I want to combine the contents of F and G into E.

```
1 JOHN JONES  | JOHN  | JONES
2             | MARY  | FORD
3 FRED MURPHY | FRED  | MURPHY
4             | TONYA | FARMER
```

I want the code to populate the empty cell in row 2 with 'MARY FORD' and row 4 with 'TONYA FARMER'.

I'm using Excel 2010 and have tried different combinations but nothing seems to work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For Each rw In UsedRange.Rows
  If rw.Columns("E") = "" Then
    rw.Columns("E") = rw.Columns("F") & " " & rw.Columns("G")
  End If
Next rw
```

Comment: It says 'Object Required' and highlights the first line of your code.

Comment: @Mr_Thomas, I ran the routine in a Click() sub for a button on a page to test it, and it worked fine, not even a Dim statement needed.  Make sure your either putting it in a Sheet module so it knows the Sheet context, or tell it that explicitly.

Comment: I have the code in a 'module', how would I tell it explicitly about the context (hope I'm saying that right -- I'm new to Excel VBA)

Comment: @Mr_Thomas, I would just create an Active-X button (non-Form) on the page I was working on.  Then right-click (in Design mode, which it would start out in), and pick 'View Code'.  This will create a Click Sub in the Sheet module, then just insert your code, go back to the page and get out of Design mode, then click the button.

Comment: Wow! That worked like a champ. However, this macro is part of a larger group of macros I'm running against the data. For 'grins', what would I add to give the sheet context?

Comment: @Mr_Thomas, well, you can either just use the ActiveSheet (if called from the button), or just to define the sheet in the beginning of the subroutine.  So in this case you'd just change the statement to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going to need a 4th column

because you need a formula or something in the blank space - however you have got text in there so you can have one or the other

if you had it like this

```
1 JOHN JONES  | =IF(A2="",CONCATENATE(C2," ",D2),A2)   | JOHN  | JONES  |
2             | =IF(A3="",CONCATENATE(C3," ",D3),A3)   | MARY  | FORD   |
3 FRED MURPHY | =IF(A4="",CONCATENATE(C4," ",D4),A4)   | FRED  | MURPHY |
4             | =IF(A5="",CONCATENATE(C5," ",D5),A5)   | TONYA | FARMER |
```

You could always hide that first column if you wanted?

This unless you want a function to run as a macro as a one time run to fill in the blanks?

Rob

Comment: Yes, I need VBA code because it's a couple thousand records. I tried something similar to your suggestion with OFFSET, but I can't get the syntax right. Here's my code: lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

a = 2
b = lastRow

Range("E" & a & ":E" & b).Select
For i = a To b
        If Range("E" & i).Text = "" Then
            Range("E" & i).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OFFSET(""F"" & i & "",0,1) & CHAR(45) & OFFSET(""H"" & i & "",0,3)"
        End If
Next i

Comment: It has a problem with the 'ActiveCell.Formula...' line.

Comment: Im afraid I dont know how to do this - only thing i'd say is if its only a couple of thousand use the little square dragger (bottomright corner) to drag the formula to the bottom of the speadsheet